# matplotlib imshow interpolation grey edges

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm using imshow to generate heat maps for a relatively sparse matrix but get grey edges when I use interpolation.
This is my code for the chart/s

```
plt.imshow(data[:,start:], cmap=cmap, interpolation='none', aspect='auto', norm=norm, origin='lower')
plt.plot(np.array(range(len(x_labels))), ave_time, color='g', alpha = 0.3, lw=1)
```

Is there a way to prevent the grey edges?

With interpolation = none
[image: With interpolation = none]

With interpolation = spline36
[image: With interpolation = spline36]

Answer (score 2):

OK, figured it out.  Added a bad data element to the colormap

cmap.set_bad('w',1.)